# Web service is deployed on Weblogic and address location in WSDL file being assigned server hostname instead of loadbalancer hostname

Tags: xml, web-services, wsdl, weblogic12c

I am trying to change the "address location" on a webservice to contain the loadbalancer hostname instead of a hardcoded server hostname it is being assigned.  This webservice is deployed on Weblogic.

The RouteLookUpService.wsdl file inside my deployed application contains the following information:

```
<s3:address location="https://{loadbalancerhost}/RouteLookUpServiceImpl/RouteLookUpServiceImpl"/>
```

however when I hit the WSDL on a web browser (https://{loadbalancerhost}/logistics/RouteLookUp/RouteLookUpServiceImpl?wsdl) I see the following:

```
<WL5G3N3:address location="https://{serverhost}:15101/logistics/RouteLookUp/RouteLookUpServiceImpl"/>
```